# Change value in row according to last occurrence

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame

```
 df <- data.frame(
        Machine_ID= c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
        Operation = c("Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start", "Stop", "Start"))

> df
   Machine_ID Operation
1           1     Start
2           1      Stop
3           1     Start
4           1      Stop
5           2      Stop
6           2      Stop
7           2     Start
8           2      Stop
9           2     Start
10          2      Stop
11          3     Start
12          3      Stop
13          3     Start
```

And I would like to correct a sequence of operation. Every machine should have an even number of operation with combination of one Start and one End.

So I would like to have df like this

```
> df
   Machine_ID Operation
1           1     Start
2           1      Stop
3           1     Start
4           1      Stop
5           2      Start
6           2      Stop
7           2     Start
8           2      Stop
9           2     Start
10          2      Stop
11          3     Start
12          3      Stop
13          3     Start
14          3      Stop
```

I tried make a loop with IF statements, but its not optimal solution for my databse.

Comment: Every machine should have an *even* number of rows? What if it doesn't? Do you want to remove the extra row or add another row? What if there are two starts or stops in a sequence, is the rule the same? Can we say that a machine needs an even sequence of starts and stops and we can ignore the current sequence?

Comment: Thank you, I just edited my post. Every machine should have even sequence of START and STOP. If it doesnt in raw dataframe it should have been edited. So if it has START and then no STOP I should add one STOP after. If it doesn't begin with START I should add a START operation as a first row. If it doesn't end with STOP I should add last row as STOP. So If it has a two STARTS in a sequence there should be a STOP between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Machine_ID) %>% 
  group_modify(~ add_row(.x,.before=0)) %>% 
  mutate(helper = ifelse(last(row_number()) %% 2 ==0, 1, 0)) %>% 
  filter(!(row_number() == last(row_number()) & helper == 0)) %>% 
  mutate(Operation = rep(c("Start", "Stop"), length.out = n()), .keep="used")


  Machine_ID Operation
        <dbl> <chr>    
 1          1 Start    
 2          1 Stop     
 3          1 Start    
 4          1 Stop     
 5          2 Start    
 6          2 Stop     
 7          2 Start    
 8          2 Stop     
 9          2 Start    
10          2 Stop     
11          3 Start    
12          3 Stop     
13          3 Start    
14          3 Stop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Machine_ID <- rep(1:4,each=4)
Operation <- rep(c("Start", "Stop"),8)

df<-cbind.data.frame(Machine_ID,Operation)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to generate an even number of rows for each machine id, if the sequence is of odd value then it adds one additional row

```
tmp=tapply(df$Operation,df$Machine_ID,length)
tmp=ceiling(tmp/2)*2

data.frame(
  "Machine_ID"=rep(names(tmp),tmp),
  "Operation"=c("Start","Stop")
)
```